# Call apex class from bot with list object as input variable

Tags: apex, einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots

I have an standard einstein bot that is calling an apex class. That apex class must accept a list of objects as input, and a string as output (with the value the the one in the first object of the list, in its field answer__c). The class is:

```
public with sharing class GetKnowledgeAnswer {
    
    @InvocableVariable(label='Input Object List' required=true)
    public List<sObject> knowledgeSearchResults;
    
    @InvocableVariable(label='Output Answer String' required=false)
    public String answer;

    @InvocableMethod(label='Get Knowledge Answer')
    public static List<GetKnowledgeAnswer> getAnswerFromKnowledge(List<GetKnowledgeAnswer> invokers) {
        for (GetKnowledgeAnswer invoker : invokers) {
            if (invoker.knowledgeSearchResults != null && !invoker.knowledgeSearchResults.isEmpty()) {
                Object firstObject = invoker.knowledgeSearchResults[0];
                if (firstObject instanceof Knowledge__kav) {
                    Knowledge__kav knowledgeObj = (Knowledge__kav) firstObject;
                    invoker.answer = knowledgeObj.Answer__c;
                } else {
                    invoker.answer = 'El primer objeto en la lista no es de tipo Knowledge__kav.';
                }
            } else {
                invoker.answer = 'La lista de objetos está vacía o es nula.';
            }
        }
        return invokers;
    }
}
```

Regarding the bot, that contains all the logic for the business process, the conflicting steps are:

Search knowledge matches:

[image: search knowledge matches]

Get answer from first match:

[image: get answer from first match]

When previewing the bot, it throws an error when calling the apex class:

Error: Error when invoking /support/conversations/0X909000000xlNF/invocations/0SC09000000xnyMGAQ: [{"actionName":"GetKnowledgeAnswer","errors":[{"statusCode":"REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING","message":"Missing required input parameter: knowledgeSearc

Why does it say "REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING"? I'm clearly passing the output from the previous step as input for the apex class. Wondering if previous block gives `List<Object>` but apex class expects `List<sObject>`? I'm totally blocked in here, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this. I am also struggling in a similar use case wherein i want to search from only a subset of knowledge articles . Since Knowledge Object search does not have a OOTB filter, i thought of taking the list returned by the object search and filter it in apex.

Answer (score 0):

I've got quite same situation with using List variables between Bot and Apex.
I decided just to use String variables in Bot and Json.serialize/deserialize combination in Apex.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).